# Unity 2.5D Character Movement

Tags: unity, sprites, 2.5d

I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direct as to how to take a 2D character/sprite in Unity and have said character turn corners in a 3D style. Solutions or resources welcome.

Comment: This is a pretty open ended question, can you add more details as to what you've tried and the specific problem you're having implementing this.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty specific question to me. Since I've never used Unity, I can't begin to answer the question, however.

Comment: What do you mean by "3D style"? Does the character turn (e.g. so you can see their back)? Does the world turn (e.g. you only see character's side)? Is the world 3D, 2D? Is the world made of models, sprites?

Comment: The idea would be imagine a 2d world where the character is walking along a corridor and hits a wall but the corridor turns to the right so the character heads right and the world pans around the character.

Comment: Not sure if this would require the world to be built in fully 3d assets or if the hallway just could rotate so that more the basic map outline was 3D in nature. Just trying to get pointed in the right direction, this is by no means in dev but rather still in the research planning phase.